# Need SharePoint 2013 Development Environment

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, development-enviroment

I am working in organization where there in not SharePoint development environment. They use only OTB Features.

I cant work on Custom WebParts, Timer Jobs and other customized things.

I want to practice these topics on SharePoint Development Server.

Organization is NOT ready to spend any cost for this development environment

Is there any another way so that I can perform my practical of SharePoint Development for my knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are trial keys for evaluation for 180 days. So you can avoid the cost of the software. Deploy it on your own machine. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-sharepoint-server-2013

Or you can sign up for Office 365 and deploy SP 2013 on Azure. 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/subscriptions-and-billing/sign-up-for-office-365-trial?view=o365-worldwide

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/get-started/

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/sharepoint-2013-dev-test-environments-in-azure

Or one year free by participating in the developer program of Office 365. See [Join the Microsoft Office 365 Developer Program](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev-program).